# If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync. RCTText

Tags: react-native, expo

I am kind of new to react native and i have been practicing with some codes but i just encountered an error that i have been trying to solve for days. In my app I'm displaying bottom navigation with some icons and it was working initially until it suddenly stopped loading icons with these errors in the terminal

```
 ERROR  fontFamily "Material Design Icons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync. 
RCTText
```

I have tried re installing `react-native-vector-icons` and deleted `node-modules` all to no avail.

this is where i load the icons

```
import MateriaCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'


render() {
return (
  <Tab.Navigator 
  activeColor="green"
  inactiveColor="black"
  barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}
  initialRouteName='Home'
  >

  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{
    title: 'home',
    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
       <MateriaCommunityIcons name='home-outline' color={color} size={26} />
    ),
  }} />   

  <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={OrderScreen} options={{
    hederTitle: 'Orders',
    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
       <MateriaCommunityIcons name='cart-arrow-down' color={color} size={26} 
/>
    ),
  }} />

<Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} navigation={this.props.navigation} options={{
    hederTitle: 'Search',
    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
       <MateriaCommunityIcons name='magnify' color={color} size={26} />
    ),
  }} />

  <Tab.Screen name="Acount" component={AcountScreen} options={{ title:'Account',
    tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
       <MateriaCommunityIcons name='account-circle-outline' color={color} size={26} />
    ),
  }} />
  
</Tab.Navigator>
)
  }
}
```

I'm confused because it was working and suddenly stopped and i think i have made some wrong changes.

Comment: @starball please can you help me solve my problem?

Comment: No. Not everyone who interacts with your post knows how to solve your problem or is willing to spend the time to. I don't have the the subject-matter-expertise to do so.